# Visual problems Midnight Commander

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, midnight-commander

I have visual problems in Ubuntu terminal working with MC. Other video features are working fine in the system. Maybe somebody know how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to gnome-terminal's Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Compatibility, check the value of Ambiguous-width characters. I assume it's set to Wide, that causes this phenomenon. Change it to the default Narrow.